# How to use azurerm_app_service_connection to configure an Azure App Service, "connection string" type Service Connector

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use the newly released (terraform-provider-azurem v3.21.0) azurerm_app_service_connection ([#16907](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16907)) resource to recreate a service connector in terraform HCL between a Web App Service and an SQL Database that I have previously generated through Azure Portal.
In Azure the Service Connector appears as follows:

- **BASICS**
- Service type: SQL database
- Subscription: "My Subscription"
- Name: "myapp-to-sql-server-north-stage"
- SQL server:   "myapp-sql-server-north-stage"
- SQL database: "mydb-north-stage"
- Client type: .NET
- **AUTHENTICATION**
- Authentication Type: "Connection string"
- Continue with... : Database credentials
- Username:  "mydbadminusername"
- Password: "mydbadminpassword" Store Secret in Key
- Vault: false
- Store in Connection Strings: true
- **NETWORKING**
- Configure firewall rules to enable access to target service

I have had several attempts at trying to replicate this service connector in terraform using the "azurem_app_service_connection" but without success (frustrating because I have been able to convert the rest of my staging infra config into terraform HCL).

The following is my latest attempt, that at least passes 'terraform validate':

```
  resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "service_connector" {
  name               = "myapp-to-sql-server-north-stage"
  app_service_id     = azurerm_windows_web_app.app_service.id
  target_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_server.mssql_server.id
  client_type = "dotnet"
  authentication {
    type = "secret"
    name = "mydbadminusername"
    secret = "mydbadminpassword"
  }
}
```

I guess the azure providers knowledge of the sql server endpoint should allow it fill in some of the SQL related fields that are selected in the portal setting but I do not see any parameters (optional or otherwise) to set a connection string though it is conceivable that the provider could deduce that from the SQL server, the server could have multiple DBs on... I am wondering if there is either a shortfall in the current implementation or another way I should be going about this with Terraform (although knowing my app can't speak to the SQL db in practice if this is not in place)?

However this throws the following error at runtime (apologies if I have botched my redaction in here):

```
module.azure_webapp.azurerm_app_service_connection.service_connector: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating Scoped Linker (Resource Uri: "/subscriptions/a4cf34e0-d62b-49de-9e83-80ae305ff15b/resourceGroups/my-resource-group-north-stage/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-app-north-stage"
│ Linker Name: "myapp_to_sql_server_connection"): servicelinker.ServiceLinkerClient#LinkerCreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="HttpRequestPayloadAPISpecValidationFailed" Message="HTTP request payload failed validation against API specification with one or more errors. Please see details for more information." Target="Microsoft.Web/sites/myapp-north-stage/providers/Microsoft.ServiceLinker/linkers/,myapp_to_sql_server_connection" Details=[{"code":"InvalidType","message":"Expected type object but found type string. Paths in payload: '$.properties.authInfo.secretInfo.secretType'"}]
│
│   with module.azure_nop_webapp.azurerm_app_service_connection.service_connector,
│   on ../modules/azure_nop_webapp/resources.tf line 91, in resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "service_connector":
│   91: resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "service_connector" {
│
│ creating Scoped Linker (Resource Uri:
│ "/subscriptions/a4cf34e0-d62b-49de-9e83-80ae305ff15b/resourceGroups/my-resource-group-north-stage/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-app-north-stage"
│ Linker Name: "myapp_to_sql_server_connection"):
│ servicelinker.ServiceLinkerClient#LinkerCreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
│ request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error:
│ Code="HttpRequestPayloadAPISpecValidationFailed" Message="HTTP request
│ payload failed validation against API specification with one or more
│ errors. Please see details for more information."
│ Target="Microsoft.Web/sites/my-app-north-stage/providers/Microsoft.ServiceLinker/linkers/app_to_sql_server_connection"
│ Details=[{"code":"InvalidType","message":"Expected type object but found
│ type string. Paths in payload:
│ '$.properties.authInfo.secretInfo.secretType'"}]
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform apply (exit 1)
```

The documentation [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/service_connector_app_service) doesn't really what I am trying to replicate explicitly so I have been trying to get through it via a process of elimination but have run out of road and am now wondering if my requirement has not yet been implemented or if I am missing something. Presumably people using terraform for infrastructure on Azure up until a month ago (when the service connection was added to the azurem provider) just added these service connector connections in manually after get the big handfuls of infrastructure in place?

Many thanks for any help on this. I guess I realise that perhaps my "lets get it working" approach up until now is not great as it leaves the dbadminpassword out in plaintext in Azure portal (I do actually substitute it with a sensitive var in HCL" but I thought I would try and get this "simpler" implementation working before standing up a Key Vault and getting into how to stand that up in Azure Portal then Terraform...

Comment: Have continued to look at this and the more I look at it the less convinced I am that there is a one-to-one mapping between creating the connection string type service connector via the portal and via Terraform (which relies on the Azure REST API I believe).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same and received the similar error when used authentication  type to be secret:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "example" {
  name               = "kaexample-serviceconnector"
  app_service_id     = azurerm_windows_web_app.example.id
  target_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_database.example.id
 
  authentication {
    type = "secret"   
    name = "4xxx0r"
    secret = "4-xxx5w0rd"
  }
}
```

[image]

Tried  with  `type = "systemAssignedIdentity"` and it worked

```
 resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "example" {
  name               = "exampleserviceconnector"
  app_service_id     = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/TestRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/TestApp6087"
  target_resource_id = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/TestRG/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/test234/databases/testsree"
  authentication {
     type = "systemAssignedIdentity"
  }
}
```

This seems to be issue from terraform API with secret type for terraform provider "azurerm_app_service_connection"  ,
you can raise an issue with terraform in below link
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues

Alternatively you can try using Azure Management Api or postman.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/serviceconnector/linker/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP

**`PUT https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/bxxxxxf/resourceGroups/v-xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/kaexamplewebapp/providers/Microsoft.ServiceLinker/linkers/kaexampleserviceconnector?api-version=2021-11-01-preview`**

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX..........xx
Content-type: application/json


 {
      "properties": {
        "targetId": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/test-account/mongodbDatabases/test-db",
        "authInfo": {
          "authType": "secret",
          "name": "secretname",
          "secret": "<your secret /pwd>"
        }
      }
    }
```

***Response:***

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/test-app/providers/Microsoft.ServiceLinker/links/linkName",
  "type": "Microsoft.ServiceLinker/links",
  "name": "linkName",
  "properties": {
    "authInfo": {
      "authType": "secret",
      "name": "secretname"
    },
    "targetId": "/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/test-rg/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/test-account/mongodbDatabases/test-db"
  }
}
```

[image]

> Note: Try to avoid spaces or `-` in the name of the service connector

Answer (score 0):

It was a Terraform client side bug and fixed in Nov 2022, should work now. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19439

For [Azure Service Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-connector/overview), Terraform only supports its very basic functions as Terrafrom requires stable api-versions. Try more features on Azure Portal and Azure CLI, where there are more convenient experience and advanced features, as well as the examples and user guidance.